# ¿Cómo comparar una tabla en MySQL con una tabla en SQLite para insertar los registros restantes?

Tags: mysql, android-studio, sqlite, jsonarray

En una app en Android tengo una base de datos que Sincroniza en ambos sentidos:
de **MySQL->SQLite**
y de **SQLite->MySQL**

La sincronización de **SQLite->MySQL** la realizo recorriendo mi **SQLiteDatabase**, posteriormente el resultado lo almaceno en un **JSONArray** y luego a través de **RequestQueue de la librería Volley** realizo la sincronización, al obtener la respuesta esperada, borro los registros de mi **SQLiteDatabase**.

Mi problema ocurre al sincronizar de **MySQL->SQLite** al momento de recorrer un **StringRequest** para obtener los registros del servidor, luego hago los **INSERT en la tabla SQLite**, los que no existen los inserta perfecto, pero los que ya existen lanzan una:

**SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: id**

Esto ocurre porque está tratando de insertar una llave que ya existe

a diferencia que el anterior, en estas tablas no puedo borrar los registros, estoy buscando la manera que sólo inserte lo que consulte en el servidor que no exista en el SQLite.

Se me ocurrió con un campo booleano en la tabla llamado actualizado pero esto le quita mucho redimiendo a mi consulta debido a que tengo que hacer varias operaciones:

1. SELECT en el SQLite
2. INSERT en el SQLite
3. UPDATE en el SERVIDOR

¿Existe una manera mas fácil de hacer esto?

Comment: Lo siguiente puede ser útil para columnas `primary key` o `unique constraints`: [ON CONFLICT Clause::IGNORE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) o [INSERT OR IGNORE](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: Hola, si buscas una opinión, te sugiero revisar [ask], saludos.